# Возврат булевых значений в списке при проверке чисел в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Функция должна принимать числа типа float и возвращать список из двух булевых значений. Первый уровень True если число бесконечное, второе значение True если число имеет значение nan. При проверки `number_checker(float("nan"))` выдает `[False, False]` вместо `[False, True]`

Код:

```
def number_checker(number: float) -> list:
    my_list = []
    
    if number == float("inf") or number == float("-inf"):
        my_list.append(True)
    else:
        my_list.append(False)

    if number == float("nan"):
        my_list.append(True)
    else:
        my_list.append(False)

    return my_list
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/944700/15035314

Comment: Спасибо огромное, получилось

Comment: Да, `nan`-ы впрямую нельзя проверять. Проверяют либо что тип определённый через `is`, но в данном случае тип `float` и так не проверить, либо подходящей функцией `isnan`, в зависимости от того, что за `nan`, из какого он пакета с данными.